# submit button on modal wont submit

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i have a form with js validation. If all inputs sets correctly it opens a modal where u can choose a redirect.

The modal opens , but it doesnt submit the form when clicking on a button..

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php" >
```

Call validation button:

```
<button  class="modal-toggle" id="lp-pom-button-40" onclick="validateForm()"   type ="button" data-toggle="modal" >Absenden</button></div>
```

Validations snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
   if( document.form1.vorname.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.nachname.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.postleitzahl.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.email.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.telefon_optin_Ja.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
    }
if( document.form1.ort.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.straße.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.Anrede.value == "" )
   {
         return false;


        }else { 
            $('#modal_absenden').modal({
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: 'false',
                 })

    }
}
</script>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_absenden">
  <div class="modal-header">

    <h3><center>Vielen Dank!</center></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"><center>
    <p>Wir werden uns in den kommenden Tagen telefonisch bei Ihnen melden.
Besuchen Sie doch in der Zwischenzeit einfach unseren Online-Shop in dem Sie über 6.000 verschiedene Artikel finden:<br>
<img src="cxds34-shop_08b05a08b05a000000.png"></img></center></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" href="www.aol.com" value="Nein, danke" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">
    <input type="submit" href="www.bing.com" class="btn btn-success" value="Ok" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

Whats wrong with the submit button on the modal?

Thanks for any hint

Comment: I'm guessing that the form needs to have it's submit button within the actual `<form>` tags.  Without more of your HTML it's hard to tell what's going on though.

Comment: there is the full code -> http://pastebin.com/BLVHgCaA

Comment: Your Absenden button probably should not have both your `onclick` handler and a `data-toggle="modal"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to remove data-toggle="modal" from the submit button(s) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please give the name of submit button like name="submit" suppose it's work.

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" href="www.aol.com" value="Nein, danke" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">
```